# Passing Arguments in a correct way to scipy minimzer

Tags: python, optimization, args, kalman-filter, minimization

I am trying to minimize a loglikelihood wrt Fsc, Qsc and Rsc:

```
def llik_scalars(Fsc, Qsc, Rsc, pred_state, pred_P, y):
T = len(pred_P)
#pred_state = np.array([pred_state[t].item() for t in range(len(pred_state))])
#pred_P = np.array([pred_P[t].item() for t in range(len(pred_P))])
Sigmat = np.array(pred_P) + Rsc
Mut = pred_state
for t in range(T):
    exponent = -0.5 * (y[t]-Mut[t])**2 / Sigmat[t]
    cc = 1 / math.sqrt(2*math.pi*Sigmat[t])
    LL -= math.log(cc*math.exp(exponent))
return LL
```

At first i tried to pass my pred_state and pred_P as lists of matrices. These matrices are of size 1x1, so with the code that is commented out i retrieved  list of the numbers in the matrices. 
However, as i was not sure the arguments could be passed in that form, but I read that arrays can be passed, the code that is commented out is now performed BEFORE i pass pred_state and pred_P as arguments. I thus pass them as numpy arrays.
I tried to do this using the scipy minimzer

```
x0 = [0.5, np.var(y)/3, np.var(y) *2/3]
minimize(llik_scalars, x0, method = 'nelder-mead', args=(pred_state, pred_P, y))
```

I get this error:

```
llik_scalars() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'pred_P' and 'y'
```

Following another topic on stackoverflow i adapted my code to the following, hoping to solve my problem:

```
def llik_scalars(Fsc, Qsc, Rsc, *args):
pred_state = args[0]
pred_P = args[1]
y = args[2]
T = len(pred_P)
#pred_state = np.array([pred_state[t].item() for t in range(len(pred_state))])
#pred_P = np.array([pred_P[t].item() for t in range(len(pred_P))])
Sigmat = np.array(pred_P) + Rsc
Mut = pred_state
for t in range(T):
    exponent = -0.5 * (y[t]-Mut[t])**2 / Sigmat[t]
    cc = 1 / math.sqrt(2*math.pi*Sigmat[t])
    LL -= math.log(cc*math.exp(exponent))
return LL
```

This however, results in the following error:

```
pred_P = args[1]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I don't see how this is not working. Please help me out :)

-- EDIT:--
the first few entries of pred_state and pred_p and y, how i pass them into llik_scalars. Note inital guess for the state is 0, and I use a sort of diffuse prior by setting my variance (pred_P) to a million. I retrieved my pred_state and pred_P using a Kalman filter with initial guesses for my F, Q and R:

```
pred_state[:5]
Out[121]: array([ 0.        ,  0.6097107 ,  0.29789331,  0.30998801, -0.33307371])

pred_P[:5]
Out[122]: 
array([1.00000000e+06, 1.24999975e+00, 1.13888888e+00, 1.13311688e+00,
       1.13280061e+00])

y[:5]
Out[123]: array([ 1.21942262,  0.58464737,  0.90278035, -1.52760793, -0.80572172])
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of your `pred_state`, `pred_P` and `y`? Let's say for T = 5. So we could debug the code.

Comment: Dear Anton, i updated / edited the initial post. Thanks for your question

Comment: If I see it correctly, your `llik_scalars()` gets `F`, `Q` and `R` as inputs, but I can find only `R` in the actual function body. Are the other two parameters (`F` and `Q`) needed?